# При попытке динамического подключения DLL ее Handle не определяется

Tags: windows, delphi, dll

Существует DLL, в ней единственная функция. Функция содержит множество локальных процедур и функций (некоторый локальный функционал). В функцию при вызове должен передаваться некоторый класс и возвращаться должен этот же класс, измененный данной функцией после ее отработки. Данный DLL нормально компилируется (без ошибок). Размер DLL  ~ 350 кб.

Проблема в том, что при подключении части локального функционала и компиляции DLL нормально загружается и отрабатывает в программе (Delphi, динамическое подключение). При подключении той части функционала весит 304 кб. Но стоит подключить весь необходимый локальный функционал и скомпилировать, то при попытке динамического подключения ее `Handle` не определяется (`=0`).

Еще один момент. Общее количество локальных функций и процедур, используемых в вызываемой экспортируемой функции около 50. Работает при подключении 42 из них. К чему я это пишу. К тому что, при подключении всех - не определяется `Handle`, но при подключении, например, 43 - работает через раз. К примеру, после компиляции 43 используемых функций. Первый запуск `Handle=0`, второй определяется и нормально отрабатывает, третий опять 0 и т.д. - это в среде. Если запустить такой exe-шник, то на 5-ый раз может отработать как надо.

Что за хр...ь вообще происходит. Может, кто сталкивался или знает возможные причины. Буду благодарен всем, кто знает или предполагает возможное решение проблемы и причину такого поведения. PS. При подключении 42 функций всегда возвращает корректный `Handle` (имеется в виду результат `LoadLibrary`) и соответственно всегда отрабатывает корректно.
`GetLastError =8` (слишком частые запросы. Не понимаю смысла этой ошибки. Функция вызывается один раз. И даже не важно что она делает внутри, если указатель на DLL получить не удается...

Comment: Первая мысль - может, имена конфликтуют?

Comment: Имена не конфликтуют. Весь функционал протестирован в программе. Работает идеально. Нет ни ошибок, ни предупреждений. Но после помещения в DLL с библиотекой творится необъяснимое....

Comment: Проблема не в именах функций и не во внутреннем содержании. Компилируется DLL корректно. Но при использовании LoadLibrery возвращается 0, соответственно невозможно даже обраться к функции.

Comment: GetLastError что даёт?

Comment: 8

Comment: 8 - слишком частые запросы.   ???
никаких запросов DLL не делает, только расчетные функции.

Comment: Может скинете нам код, если он не секретный?
И как вариант увеличить ***Maximum Stack Size***

Comment: Maximum Stack Size увеличивать - я думаю, что не в этом дело.
Хотя уж и это пробовали еще с самого начала - это не помогает. Код скинуть к сожалению не могу - как раз секретный.

Comment: Вообще такая ситуация возникает не в первый раз. Ранее случалось не определялись DLL  и на порядок меньшего размера. Проблема в LoadLibrary - а это от кода не зависит, я думаю...
Если когдато найду решение - обязательно выложу здесь в виде ответа для всех.

Answer (score 1):

Одна из возможных причин такого поведения - какая-то ошибка (исключение), возникающая в DllMain или конструкторе глобальных/статических переменных в DLL. Возможно, что имеет место какой-то конфликт с уже загруженными компонентами (например, дважды вызывается какая-нибудь инициализация)

Comment: спасибо! Этот вариант причины поведения пока не рассматривался. Возможность рассмотреть будет в конце недели - обязательно отпишусь о результате...

Comment: @NNT Хотелось бы уточнить, "в конце недели" какого года? :) Судя по тому, что автор вопроса не отписался, проблема была успешно локализована.